# How to control Animation when open/closing a Prism IDialogService Dialogue on Xamarin Forms

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, dialog, prism

Is there a way to enable/disable the animation when a dialog is opened / closed for dialogs in my Xamarin Forms applications? I know I can control this using the Rg Popup control, But my 1st choice is to use the IDialogService built in to Prism.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this?